# Spring Framework ClassPathXmlApplicationContext Hangs

Tags: spring, visual-studio-code, spring-context

I did find this previous question but this does not seem to be my issue:

[Spring hangs when loading bean definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815065/spring-hangs-when-loading-bean-definitions)

The situation is with Spring Framework 5.3.29 under OpenJDK8.  I have this code:

```
System.out.println("Loading beans.xml from classpath");
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:beans.xml");
System.out.println("Loaded beans.xml from classpath.\nRunning helloWorld.");
```

and this is my beans.xml:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id = "helloWorld" class = "net.application.spring.HelloWorld">
      <property name = "message" value = "Hello World!"/>
   </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://blahblahblah" />
        <property name="username" value="some_user" />
        <property name="password" value="some_password" />
    </bean>

   <bean id = "exceptionDataDAO" class = "net.application.spring.ExceptionDataDAOImpl">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

When I run the application, with or without debug in VSCODE, it runs normally.  But if I build a JAR file and try to run that, the application just hangs at:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:beans.xml");
```

I'm building using Maven with:

> mvn clean compile assembly:single

Comment: could you please add the command that you used for running the build

Comment: I updated the question with the build command.